# How to parse html tags in CodeKicker BB Code Core

Tags: html, html-parsing, bbcode

I am trying to parse the following string content using **CodeKicker BBCode Core**.

```
String to parse = [urltab=www.google.com]www.google.com[/urltab]
Expected output = <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>

Actual output = <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">&lt;!-- m --&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;//www.google.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;www.google.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;!-- m --&gt;</a>
```

As you can see there is additional tags in the actual output.

I'm using the following method to parse the string to html content.

```
public string ParseStringToBBCode(string content)
{
    var htmlBbCodeParser = GetHtmlBbParser();
    var htmlContent = htmlBbCodeParser.ToHtml(content);
            
    return htmlContent;
}
```

Is there a way to get the expected output as mentioned for this scenarion?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

Created a new tag as [noparse] and wrapped the content that is not required to be passed within that tag.

Example :

Modified input as

```
[urltab=www.google.com][noparse]www.google.com[/noparse][/urltab]
```

Modified GetHtmlBbParser() method and added new tag.

```
new BBCodeParser(new []
{
   new BBTag("noparse", "", "", 1, allowUrlProcessingAsText: false),
}
```

Answer 2:
Modified [url] and [urltab] tags initialization.

> Set allowUrlProcessingAsText: false

```
new BBCodeParser(new []
{
    new BBTag("url", "<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"${target}\">", "</a>", 19, allowUrlProcessingAsText: false,attributes: new BBAttribute[] { new BBAttribute("href", ""), new BBAttribute("href", "href"), new BBAttribute("target", ""), new BBAttribute("target", "target") }),
    new BBTag("urltab", "<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"_blank\">", "</a>", 20, allowUrlProcessingAsText: false, attributes: new BBAttribute[] { new BBAttribute("href", ""), new BBAttribute("href", "href") })
}
```